# Restrict number of characters in JqxGrid

Tags: jqxgrid

I have a jqxGrid as below and i want to restrict number of characters in jqxGrid.

```js
columns : [ {
text :
‘Type’,datafield : ‘type’, width : 150, align : ‘center’,cellsalign : ‘left’, editable : false
}, {
text :
‘Phase’,datafield : ‘phase’, width : 150, align : ‘center’,cellsalign : ‘left’, editable : false
},{
text :
‘Phase Description’,datafield : ‘phaseDescription’, width : 150, align : ‘center’,cellsalign : ‘left’, editable : false
},{
text :
‘Custom Phase’, datafield : ‘customPhase’, width : 150, align : ‘center’, cellsalign : ‘left’
}
```

for the column ‘Custom Phase’ i need to restrict user entry to 10 characters. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to use [jqwidget](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxvalidator/jquery-validator-getting-started.htm) validation and include the file jqxvalidator.js in your view file and use this code in column:

```js
 columns : [ {
text :
‘Type’,datafield : ‘type’, width : 150, align : ‘center’,cellsalign : ‘left’, editable : false
}, {
text :
‘Phase’,datafield : ‘phase’, width : 150, align : ‘center’,cellsalign : ‘left’, editable : false
},{
text :
‘Phase Description’,datafield : ‘phaseDescription’, width : 150, align : ‘center’,cellsalign : ‘left’, editable : false
},{
text :
‘Custom Phase’, datafield : ‘customPhase’, width : 150, align : ‘center’, cellsalign : ‘left’,
     validation: function (cell, value) 
              {
                if (value.length > 10) {
                   return { result: false, message: "character should be  maximum 10" };
                }
              return true;
              }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This demo use of the column's "validation" function: [cellediting.htm](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/cellediting.htm?arctic).

```
 validation: function(cell, value)
 {
    if (value.toString().length > 10)
    {
        return { result: false, message: "entered text should be less than 10 characters"}
    }
    return true;
 }
```

toString() is required because the value could be Number or Date object.